# Наследование перегруженных арифметических операторов c++

Tags: c++, ооп, наследование, перегрузка-операторов

Есть шаблонные классы

```
template< int rows, int columns, typename Type >
class Matrix : public Tensor<rows*columns, Type> {...}

template< int size, typename Type >
class Vector : public Tensor<size, Type> {...}

template< typename Type >
class Quaternion : public Tensor<4, Type> {...}
```

Которые все унаследованы от шаблонного базового класса:

```
template< int elements, typename Type = DEFUALT_TYPE >
class Tensor {
  Tensor() {...}
  Tensor( const Tensor<elements, Type>& other ) {...}
 ~Tensor() {...}

  template< int elements, typename Type, typename Scalar >
  friend Tensor< elements, Type> operator+( const Tensor< elements, Type>& left, const Scalar right );
  ...
  // overloading operators -,*,/,+=,-=,*=,/=
protected:
  Type array[elements];
}
```

Который, в основном, отвечает за базовые арифметические операции: сложение, вычитание, умножение, деление на скаляр, так как для всех наследованных типов эти операции одинаковы.

Но проблема в том, что эти операторы возвращают базовый класс Tensor, что, в свою очередь, порождает некоторые проблемы:

1. Нельзя присвоить результат сложение вектора и скаляра вектору:

   ```
   Vector<3,double> vec1;
   Vector<3,doubel> vec2 = vec1+1;
   ```
2. Для классов Matrix, Vector, Quaternion перегружен оператор стандартного вывода, но такое не сработает:

   ```
   std::cout << vec1+2;
   ```
3. Нельзя сразу же использовать результат сложения:

   ```
   (vec1+5).length();
   ```

Хотя, это почти то же самое что и 2 пункт.

Первую проблему можно решить, например, создав для Matrix, Vector, Quaternion конструктор копирования, который бы создавал объект из объекта класса Tensor:

```
Vector( const Tensor<size, Type>& tensor ) : Tensor<size, Type>( tensor ) {...}
```

Но это не решает остальных проблем, и пропускает такой, заведомо ложный код:

```
Matrix<2,2,double> mat1;
Vector<4,double> vec1 = mat1+2;
```

Сейчас я решил проблему тем, что для каждого наследуемого класса я определяю эти операторы заново. Но это во-первых муторно, ведь для каждого класса их примерно 12 штук. А если надо что-то поменять? Добавить новый класс? А во-вторых это дублирование идентичного кода.

Как можно разрешить эту проблему поэлегантнее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться техникой известной под именем [CRTP](http://scrutator.me/post/2014/06/26/crtp_demystified.aspx).
Приведу пример, как Вам можно это реализовать, а Вы уже сами заточите под свой код:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename Derived>
class Base
{
public:
    Derived operator+(int scalar)
    {
        //добавим сюда сложение
        return *self();
    }
private:
    Derived* self()
    {
        return static_cast<Derived*>(this);
    }
};

template<typename T>
class A: public Base<T, A<T>>
{
public:
    A() = default;
    A(const A&)
    {
        std::cout << "A copy ctor\n";
    }
};

template<typename T>
class B: public Base<T, B<T>>
{
public:
    B() = default;
    B(const B&)
    {
        std::cout << "B copy ctor\n";
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    A<int> a;
    B<float> b;
    a = a + 1;
    b = b + 5;

    // Следующие строки не скомпилируются
    //a = b + 1;
    //b = a + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Сразу скажу, что ответ не претендует на звание максимально полного. Имхо, лучший ответ стоит искать в реализации [популярных математических библиотек](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_libraries#C.2B.2B). Но для решения обозначенных проблем могу предложить следующие решения:

- Для запрета неявного преобразования `Tensor` в `Vector` достаточно
  сделать соответствующий конструктор явным:

  ```
  explicit Vector(const Tensor<size, Type>& tensor);
  ```
- Для реализации бинарных операторов типа `operator+` всё таки придется
  определеять его для каждого нового класса. Необходимость этого вытекает
  из-за возвращения нового свежесозданного объекта (а не ссылки на
  существующий). При этом код оператора каждого нового класса вполне
  может использовать вызов оператора базового класса, уменьшая таким
  образом дублирование кода.

В качестве демонстрации прилагаю код с иерархией из двух классов. Параллели с тензорами, матрицами и векторами попробуйте провести сами.

```
#include <iostream>

struct B {
    B(int i): i{i} {}
    int i;
};

B operator+(const B& lhs, const B& rhs) { return B(lhs.i + rhs.i); } 

struct D : B {
    explicit D(int i, double j=0) : B{i}, j{j} {}
    explicit D(const B& b, double j=0): B{b}, j{j} {}
    double j;
};

D operator+(const D& lhs, const D& rhs) { 
    return D(static_cast<const B&>(lhs) + static_cast<const B&>(rhs), lhs.j + rhs.j); 
} 

D operator+(const D& lhs, const B& rhs) { 
    return D(static_cast<const B&>(lhs) + static_cast<const B&>(rhs), lhs.j); 
} 

D operator+(const B& lhs, const D& rhs) { 
    return D(static_cast<const B&>(lhs) + static_cast<const B&>(rhs), rhs.j); 
} 

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const B& b) {
    return o << b.i;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const D& d) {
    return o << static_cast<const B&>(d) << ' ' << d.j;
}


int main() 
{
    D d{1, 2.25};

    B b{5};

    std::cout << d + 2 << '\n';
    std::cout << 2 + d << '\n';
    std::cout << b + d << '\n';
    std::cout << d + b << '\n';
    std::cout << b + 3 << '\n';
    std::cout << 3 + b << '\n';
    std::cout << (d + 10).j << '\n';
}
```

[<kbd>Результаты выполнения</kbd>](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/q2p433nm2FLCca65)